# My comboboxes never display as they should

Tags: c#, .net

I am working on C# application. I have a combobox labeled `Town (translated in English)`. Here you can take a look at it: [image]. When the form loads, it is always blank instead of displaying the first item in its item collection (as I imagine it should do). What can I do? Where is the problem with it?

P.S. Its item don't come from a data binding system, they are just o collection of items.

Comment: Just set the SelectedIndex property to 0 inside the Form load event

Answer (score 2):

use SelectedIndex Property and set it to 0.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.combobox.selectedindex.aspx

Answer (score 1):

In the loading of the Form or another event set following line:

```
TownComboBox.SelectedIndex = 0;
//TownComboBox being the name of the control
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(myComboBox.Items > 0)
    myCombobox.SelectedIndex(0);
```